# Can't install create-react-app on windows 10

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Tried to install create-react-app several times but nothing worked.
It gives some error like Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing...

re-installed node but still the same error.
[image]

Comment: had you solved this problem,  Please I am suffering

Comment: Yes i have , just clean the cache.

Comment: then accept that answer which solved your problem, This help others to know what solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clearing your npm cache, worked for me

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 3):

are you opening cmd with administrator privilege,

If not then, please open it with administrator privilege

if that not solve then,try to clear cache

```
npm cache clean
```

or force clean it

```
 npm cache clean --force
```